# How can I hide ADB status to apps?

Tags: adb

my bank app, for some unknown reason, refuses to start if USB debugging is enabled. It can run without problem if the device is bootloader unlocked and rooted, but for some reason, the developers are checking ADB status, and if debugging is enabled (no computer connected), it tells me that I have to disable it before starting the app.

Now, since this is illogical, I am searching for a way to hide ADB status.

On my device, a Xiaomi Mi 5x, I need to VPN into China each time I need to enable ADB (they did this "for safety"/limit grey market), so I have no intention to disable it, ever.

Can I hide it, even with root?

Comment: Have you tried Magisk? It even makes your rooted device pass SafetyNet, so you can still use Pokemon GO and Android Pay and many other bank apps. https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445

Comment: I tried using Magick hide with that app, but it still detects that adb is enabled. I dunno, their testers don't use adb? This artificial block doesn't make sense, what kind o hack i could do with adb? See logcat in real time?